# Terraform Cloud + CICD

Tags: gitlab, terraform, bitbucket-pipelines, terraform-cloud

I am struggling to get Terraform Cloud to work remotely as I would like it to.

I have the following to work with (changing these is not an option):

- Infrastructure code (Terraform) in a GitLab repo
- App code in a BitBucket repo
- CICD using BitBucket Pipelines

Terraform Cloud is used for running plan and apply. Currently manually. I want to be able to run terraform plan and apply from CICD.

I've got a `terraform.tf` file in the root of my app repo. It defines Terraform Cloud as my backend and provides a token.

My bitbucket pipelines is like so:

```
    - step:
        name: "Terraform testing"
        image: hashicorp/terraform:0.15.3
        script:
          - export TF_LOG=trace
          - export TF_WORKSPACE=testworkspace
          - terraform init
          - terraform validate
          - terraform plan
```

When I run this pipeline, Terraform is expecting the terraform config files to exist, but they are stored in the GitLab repo. The Terraform Workspace "testworkspace" is connected to the GitLab repo. I was hoping that when I ran `terraform plan` it would remotely run the workspaces plan, just as if I had clicked on it via the UI.

Do you have any suggestions regarding the above?

Comment: Assuming this is remote execution via the CLI and not API given the code above, you would need your pipeline in bitbucket to retrieve your config from gitlab. Retrieving the config from the repository is generally required in any TF pipeline arch.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard I have moved onto using the API as I think it is simpler. Appreciate your response :)